# Single SQL to aggregate data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following three tables:

The "users" table:

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- username
- password

The "users_addresses" table:

- address_id
- user_id
- street
- country_id
- email

The "countries" table

- country_id
- name

A user can have multiple addresses, but each user has at least one address.

What I would like to do is to write a single query to get all the users with their latest address.

I tried this query, but apparently, it doesn't return the latest address if there's more than one address for a user:

```
SELECT u.first_name
     , u.last_name
     , u.username
     , u.password
     , a.user_id
     , a.street
     , a.email
     , c.name 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_addresses ua 
    ON ua.user_id = u.user_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN countries c 
    ON ua.country_id = c.country_id 
 GROUP 
    BY a.user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY u.last_name ASC
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define the "latest" address?

Comment: By the higher address_id.

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM users_adresses JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(address_id) max_address_id FROM users_addresses GROUP BY user_id) y On y.user_id = x.user_id AND y.max_address_id = x.address_id;

Comment: @Strawberry, the country name must also be present in the results.

Comment: I think you can figure that bit out

Comment: Actually, I can't even figure it out how can I get the first_name, last_name and username fields :(